# Автозапуск программы C# на Raspbian

Tags: c#, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

У меня есть две Raspberry 4 B. На них установлена Raspbian 11 arch 64. Я так понимаю, что эта система произошла от Debain. На обоих в папке /usr/lib/MyProgram/ лежит папка с программой, написанной на C#. Вручную и там и там запускается. Запускается, если сделать старым способом через bashrc, правда для этого нужно запускать вручную консоль. И там и там реализован автозапуск через /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart где последней строчкой:

```
@/usr/lib/MyProgram/linux-arm/MyProgramSoftware -F
```

И в одном случае работает, а в другом нет. Я не могу понять почему. Конечная задача получить автозапуск программы, не обязательно так. Я пробовал использовать так же варианты со строками `@/usr/lib/MyProgram/linux-arm/MyProgramSoftware` и `@DISPLAY=:0 /usr/lib/MyProgram/linux-arm/MyProgramSoftware`. Пробовал делать сервис, добавляя эти же строчки в NewService.service по вот этой статье: [linux-service-creation](https://tech-geek.ru/linux-service-creation/)

Comment: "что эта система произошла от Fedora." нет Debian-based

Comment: а какие-то ошибки выдает? логи?

Comment: Да что-то нет ничего или не знаю где смотреть. Т.е. при запуске из консоли всё запускается, без ошибок.

Comment: если вы запустили сервис через `systemd`, то логи можно посмотреть `sudo journalctl -xeu <service_name>`

Comment: Мой вариант очень похож на тот, что в ответе ниже. Не пойму, почему его заминусили, возможно, потому что только для консольной программы, хотя по идее и для GUI должен работать. Или нет? По поводу логов. Правда, смотрел через systemctl status, сейчас попробую и Ваш вариант. Active: failed (Result: exit-code). Потом ругается на библиотеки проекта (Avalonia).

Comment: sudo journalctl -xeu <service_name> выдал те же ошибки, но ещё есть No protocol specified. И если я правильно понял, в предыдущем запуске Can't open display.

Comment: @Alexandr для gui нужно положить в /etc/systemd/user/myserver.service и ещё установить ожидание и параметры дисплея

Answer (score 0):

Если программе не нужен дисплей (консольная программа)

Файл для запуска `/etc/systemd/system/myserver.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Server
    
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/lib/MyProgram/linux-arm/MyProgramSoftware -F
WorkingDirectory=/usr/lib/MyProgram/
Restart=always
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Запуск

```
systemctl start myserver.service
```

Автозапуск

```
systemctl enable myserver.service
```

Логи службы ( -e конец, -f следовать):

```
journalctl -u myserver.service -e -f
```